# which strength should I use to get mobile data(mobile internet)?

Tags: android

I see there are two different interfaces for the topic "strength" of the mobile signal.
What I want is to get speed-level of the internet of sim-card. What should I use?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html

*No permission only calling listener, I know some solutions*

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrength.html

*Permission*: In order to get `cellSignalStrength` from `TelephonyManager`, I need the permission of coarse location.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find answer without location:
https://gist.github.com/XinyueZ/fe5f86734730a25638665ad77819d4f8